# Other websites' content accessible through own domain in shared hosting?

Tags: shared-hosting

I have a website in a shared hosting environment. Recently I found out that I can load other websites' contents using my own domain through URLs like `mysite.com/~othersite/`. This has resulted in Google indexing a malicious phishing website through my domain and sent me warning emails about it.

Tech support say this is normal behavior and if it bothers me I should upgrade to a VPS. They confirmed that I cannot correct this in my own .htaccess file or by other means as this happens at a higher level.

My question: Is this the usual, best-practice configuration for shared hosting environments or is the hosting company incompetent (or deliberately creating inconvenience to motivate upgrading)?

Am I requesting something overly technically complicated when I say that content from website X should under no circumstances be returned when the request is addressed with the domain of website Y? Is this an unrealistic expectation in a shared environment?

Comment: If the url situation is EXACTLY the way you describe then yes your host is noob and they have incorrectly set up the server. I would ask for all your money back and move to a competent host. The only time you should be able to see other shared service content is if you don't have an SSL and you're trying to use https mode.

Comment: I second @dhaupin on this. I used to be a web-host and back in the day the whole ~ thing was the lazy and insecure way to handle things. As well, there is no way that you should be able to access another site from your domain name. Forget upgrading!! Change hosts immediately! Find a quality host without saying a word and just change hosts with a bit of overlap for when the DNS changes so that your site stays up. Then cancel you current host. Hell! If I were still doing the hosting thing, I would not even charge you for a few months just to get you started in the right direction.

Comment: This is a major player in the hosting business, at least that is the impression I got when reading reviews. Not sure if I can name them here.

Comment: Yeah. This should not happen and if they are incompetent enough to do this, then how can you trust them with your site?? What if this breaks security further and give people more access to your site than you anticipate?

Comment: To help (short-term) fix this problem on your site (having other sites indexed under yours), you could perhaps block all `/~` URLs in robots.txt.

Comment: "Not sure if I can name them here" - go on, we _need_ to know! :)

Comment: @w3d you can't use regexes in robots.txt. Anyway, I notified them and I find it more ethical to let them fix it first. Anyone can make mistakes.

However, to be honest, I don't know how widespread this is with other hosting companies, that's why I asked here. Maybe this is not so extraordinary as I seem to view it. I was really surprised to see it. I need to get more opinions from more experienced webmasters to see if it is really something to be concerned about or rather some mildly annoying but normal and harmless stuff.

Comment: "you can't use regexes in robots.txt." - I wasn't. robots.txt is prefix matching. So `Disallow: /~` will block all URLs that start `/~` from being crawled.

Answer (score 1):

Is it really `mysite.com/~othersite` and not `hostingcompany.com/~othersite` or `ip.address/~othersite`.

They are perfectly normal ways of people using temporary URLs to view a website before DNS changes

Comment: It is mysite.com/~otheruser.

Comment: Sorry, I have a hosting business and a dedicated server and have never seen that happen.

Comment: Okay. I can see that it affects all websites using this hosting company, so I notified them about the seriousness of the issue.

Comment: `mysite.com/~otheruser` - Where "otheruser" is the _username_ used on the other account, not the _domain_ as could perhaps be inferred by `~othersite` in your question? Unfortunately, on a shared server `mysite.com` is going to resolve to the shared server IP and this behaviour is not that uncommon - although I'm sure the host can block this in the server config and make sure it is _only_ accessible by the IP?!

Comment: Not all sites will actually function correctly when accessed this way since client-side root-relative links will break. You can certainly prevent _your_ site from being accessed this way by checking the `Host:` header in the request and sending a 403 if it's not what you expect.

Comment: @w3d ~otheruser, yes. I know it resolves to a shared IP, but then the Host header should have priority, even if the folder /~otheruser exists. I can not prevent it from happening on my site as I specifically stated in my question. The Host is always my domain. The problem is that the request url is this /~otheruser and it simply goes into that folder and loads that site. I can not block this behavior with a .htaccess as these requests don't go through my .htaccess at all. They go straight into otheruser's folder and his .htaccess kicks in. So only they could return the 403 error, not me.

Comment: FWIW, I've noticed on other hosts where this happens, that the _othersite_ is only accessible if you use your bare domain ie. `mysite.com/~otheruser` and not `www.mysite.com/~otheruser` (`www` being a CNAME in DNS). The point being, that if your canonical URL contains `www` then it is unlikely that the _othersite_ could get indexed under yours. (Or/and use robots.txt as mentioned above.)

Comment: "So only they could return the 403 error, not me." - Yes, that's what I said. "You can .. prevent your site from being accessed this way". ie. `othersite.com/~yourusername`.